# How To Rounding BigDecimal with Scale zero

Tags: java

I have a BigDecimal

262727.00 / 48 = 5473.479166666666667

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("5473.479166666666667");
value = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println(value.toString());
```

I expect to get 5474 but I got 5473.
Has someone idea, how to get the number 5474?

Thank you

Comment: "I expect 5474" why?

Comment: Have a look at the `RoundingMode` doc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: @AndyTurner 5473.479 to round should be 5473.48 -> 5473.5 -> 5474. Am I misunderstand about the rounding? If I try with 5473.532, I get 5474. It round just the last number before scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` round towards the "nearest neighbor". **.479** is closer to **0** than **1**, so it rounds down.

Base on the comments you need to call `setScale()` twice, once to get the closest decimal and then the closest number

```
value = value.setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Comment: But I don't expect 5471.4327 become 5472. It will happen when I use `RoundingMode.UP`.

Comment: @Ndrik7 You want `.479` to be round up but `.432` to be round down?. Perhaps you should explain the logic.

Comment: `5473.479` to round should be `5473.48` -> `5473.5` -> `5474`. But I understand with your explanation. I think, I need to rearrange my logic.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what behavior you want for roundinf negative numbers. So, I would say, `RoundingMode.CEILING` and `RoundingMode.UP` will work in your case.

**The difference is only for negative values:**

1. **CEILING** - Rounding mode to round towards positive infinity.

   ```
   BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("-5473.479166666666667");
   value = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING);
   ```

   gives -5473
2. **UP** - Rounding mode to round away from zero.

   ```
   BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("-5473.479166666666667");
   value = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP);
   ```

   gives -5474